# Why are threads synchronizing only with large intervals?

Tags: linux, multithreading, zeromq, freepascal

FPC 3.0.0, Lazarus 1.6.0

I have two threads on a Linux machine (I will check on Windows later, this code is supposed to be cross-platform), the main thread and the client thread. The purpose of the client thread is to provide non-blocking request-reply network functionality.

The `pascal` client (requester) communicates with a server, written in `python` (replier).

I am using `ZeroMQ` **`REQ/REP`** to the low level stuff, versions at the end.

In the high level, creating and starting the client thread goes like this:

```
//from the main thread
FClientThread.Create('tcp://localhost:5020');
FClientThread.Start;
```

To send a request:

```
//from the main thread
FClientThread.SendRequest('im_requesting_stuff',-1,'give_it_to_me');
Sleep(1000)
FClientThread.SendRequest('requesting',-1,'gimme_more'); 

//the TClientThread descends from TThread.
procedure TClientThread.SendRequest(ACode: string; ATrialIndex: integer;
  ARequest: string);
begin
  FRequest := ARequest;
  FCode := ACode;
  FTrialIndex := IntToStr(ATrialIndex);
  RTLeventSetEvent(FRTLEvent);
end;

procedure TClientThread.Execute;
var
  AMessage : UTF8String;
begin
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      AMessage := '';
      RTLeventWaitFor(FRTLEvent);

      FRequester.send( FRequest );
      FRequester.recv( AMessage ); // blocking code,
                                   // that is why it is inside the thread

      // *****************************************************************************
      // BUG: These vars are being filled with the last values of
      //            ( 'FTrialIndex',               'AMessage',               'FCode' )
      FMsg := #40#39 + FTrialIndex + #39#44#32#39 + AMessage + #39#44#32#39 + FCode + #39#41;
      // 
      // *****************************************************************************

      Synchronize( @Showstatus );
    end;
end;
```

The server side works in a non-blocking fashion, single thread:

```py
while True:
   msg = self.socket.recv(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
   # do stuff
   self.socket.send(response)
```

The commented bug ( repetition of the last call ) occurs ONLY if `.SendRequest()` is called multiple times in very short intervals (without the `sleep()`, for example).

I was expecting some losses, but I was not expecting repetition since I am explicitly waiting for the main thread to return.

Any suggestions?

Best Regards

---

Edit 1:

## ZMQ versions

### python

```
# zmq
print zmq.zmq_version()
# 4.1.2

# pyzmq
print zmq.__version__
# 15.1.0
```

### pascal

For [delphizmq](https://github.com/bvarga/delphizmq/commits/master) version see commit (50a28b4b72c531536452ee5d79e19f5960c9f7c7).

```
// zmq
ZMQVersion(minor,major,patch)
WriteLn(minor,major,patch)
// 3.2.5
```

---

Edit 2:

## Logs

Legend:

> LogTickCount : ('REQTickCount', 'TestCode:DeltaTime')

Before copying Fvariables to local variables:

```
4476.028775652 : [debug] TClockThread.Execute:Start 140736007759616
4476.087363892 : ('4476.08701411', 'S:7.316086894')
4478.567764596 : ('4478.56744415', '*R:9.828251263')
4478.923743380 : ('4478.92343718', 'R:10.192552661')
4479.134910639 : [debug] C: expected next
4479.166311115 : ('4479.16600296', 'R:10.424417498') // BUG
4479.201287606 : ('4479.20099538', 'R:10.424417498') 
4483.037278107 : ('4483.03664644', '2b:14.322538449')
4483.868644929 : ('4483.86663063', '*R:15.153748820')
4484.278650579 : ('4484.27829493', 'R:15.562894551')
4484.552199446 : [debug] C: expected next
// data lost
4484.594517381 : ('4484.59364657', 'R:15.841710775')
4490.088956444 : ('4490.08862455', '1b:21.318677098')
4490.465529156 : ('4490.46522659', '*R:21.738692793')
4490.744151772 : ('4490.74376093', 'R:22.027325175')
4491.047253601 : [debug] C: expected next
4491.064188821 : ('4491.0638315', 'R:22.336764091') // BUG
4491.100142009 : ('4491.09978804', 'R:22.336764091')
4496.084726117 : ('4496.08441014', '2a:27.320218402')
4496.494107080 : ('4496.49378719', '*R:27.762184396')
4496.816623032 : ('4496.81630259', 'R:28.100685410')
4497.088603481 : [debug] C: expected next
// data lost
4497.132445971 : ('4497.13214788', 'R:28.378107825')
```

After copying Fvariables to local variables (note: data was not lost for pure lucky):

```
8183.233467050 : [debug] TClockThread.Execute:Start 140736477513472
8183.299773049 : ('8183.29946881', 'S:10.678368191')
8183.751976738 : ('8183.7516616', '*R:11.182574383')
8184.262027198 : ('8184.26170452', 'R:11.690292332')
8184.501553063 : [debug] C: is expected next
8184.517362396 : ('8184.51705341', 'C:11.952652441')
8184.552388891 : ('8184.55206258', 'R:11.950063743')
8189.291033037 : ('8189.29070225', '2b:16.683417064')
8189.880999859 : ('8189.88067746', '*R:17.299351333')
8190.257476710 : ('8190.25714788', 'R:17.699402216')
8190.515557895 : [debug] C: is expected next
8190.553234830 : ('8190.55290992', 'C:17.966527084')
8190.588187291 : ('8190.5878607', 'R:17.964049297')
8196.243242766 : ('8196.24264239', '1b:23.683231358')
8196.758162472 : ('8196.75784342', '*R:24.200630247')
8196.964202600 : ('8196.96383131', 'R:24.397590095')
8197.119091206 : [debug] C: is expected next
8197.142731450 : ('8197.14240346', 'C:24.570427216')
8197.177078782 : ('8197.17673878', 'R:24.567590990')
8208.243614030 : ('8208.24296169', '2a:35.685189479')
8208.659747197 : ('8208.65940133', '*R:36.092803071')
8208.794614317 : ('8208.79431818', 'R:36.230488258')
8208.909275842 : [debug] C: is expected next
8208.935924407 : ('8208.93559782', 'C:36.360198934')
8208.970681025 : ('8208.9703712', 'R:36.357781493')
```

Turns out that using **critical sections** was not necessary for my specific implementation.

---

Edit 3.:

Please, note that the present question **IS NOT** about data loss (queuing requests). It is about thread synchronization (variable sharing). Regarding the data loss, using `Sleep()` would be merely a hack (you should use queues).

I have tested the code with `Sleep(10)` and it reduces the chances of data loss. But you should note that it is a lucky based hack.

Comment: It depends what do you expect. You wait and then set event multiple times even though the thread is not waiting. You change variables in a thread when it can be processing older request (not thread safe). You should probably create a thread safe queue (some list) and then process one request after each other.

Comment: Log what the server sends. Is the duplication there?

Comment: Also, stop using @ with procedural variables. It disables type checking. Remove that @.

Comment: Which **`ZeroMQ`** version(s) does your code depend on? Both the python side `pyzmq.__version__` and the pascal-side binding's version, please. Currently I diagnose a code, which under stress starts to produce garbage in otherwise clean working inter-process messaging, which worked fine prior to updating to `py_27 (2.7.11)` and recent `pyzmq ( 15.2.0 )` using another vs2008_runtime: `9.00.30729.1-0`. Thanks for your kind cooperation.

Comment: ZeroMQ => REQ is 3.2.5, REP is 4.0.1. I need some time to post the logs. I will do it on Tuesday, afternoon. @DavidHeffernan,'@' have a different meaning on free pascal with the {$mode objfpc}{$H+}, it does not prevent type cheking as you said (as far as I know).

Comment: The question is tagged Delphi

Comment: and freepascal, also, this is a minor difference in the dialect not direcly related to the target problem.

Comment: @smooty86, you are right. I was expecting some losses (some calls to a thread that is not waiting). I was not expecting duplications of older requests. Duplications are challenging my comprehension of the variable sharing system.

Comment: @user3666197, I am sorry, python => zmq._version__ is (15.1.0), zmq.zmq_version() is 4.1.2. Pascal => ZMQVersion(3,2,5)

Comment: So I cannot tell what compiler you are using. Why don't you tag the question with Delphi or Free Pascal but not both.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, done.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you please chime in [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322387/may-i-use-freepascal-and-delphi-tags-together-in-this-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some locking mechanism to read and write the values from different threads.

To have only small locking times make a copy of the data.

```
TClientThread = class( TThread )
private
  FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
  ...
end;

//the TClientThread descends from TThread.
procedure TClientThread.SendRequest(ACode: string; ATrialIndex: integer;
  ARequest: string);
begin
  FCriticalSection.Enter;
  try
    FRequest := ARequest;
    FCode := ACode;
    FTrialIndex := IntToStr(ATrialIndex);
  finally
    FCriticalSection.Leave;
  end;
  RTLeventSetEvent(FRTLEvent);
end;

procedure TClientThread.Execute;
var
  lRequest: string;
  AMessage : UTF8String;
begin
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      AMessage := '';
      RTLeventWaitFor(FRTLEvent);

      FCriticalSection.Enter;
      try
        // copy data to local vars
        lRequest := FRequest;
      finally
        FCriticalSection.Leave;
      end;

      FRequester.send( lRequest );
      ...
```

Comment: I will test this on Tuesday, afternoon (UTC-3), thanks in advance for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly because of the scheduling. You created an executable code (the thread) with `FClientThread.Create('tcp://localhost:5020');` and told the O.S. "thread is ready, you can schedule it whenever it's time" with `FClientThread.Start;`

Sending parameters with `FClientThread.SendRequest('im_requesting_stuff',-1,'give_it_to_me');` does not guarantee that your thread will run immidiately. Current context would be with the main thread and scheduler couldn't have had started your newly created thread, just yet. And `Sleep(1000)` doesn't change much within scheduling perspective. If your code works with `Sleep(1000)` then believe me it's pure luck; why? You cannot determine when the scheduler schedules your thread, that's why.. So when you invoke `FClientThread.SendRequest('requesting',-1,'gimme_more');` you'd be still in your main thread and set the client thread's variables. Whenever your client thread get scheduled it uses its current variables, which were set twice in this example.

Blocking parameter passing mechanism should be implemented in `SendRequest` method, I think. And be sure there are a lot of ways to achieve.

Long story short, it's all about thread synchronisation and scheduling.

PS: `Sleep(0)` would get around the problem, but not just solve it completely. Synchronisation problem is still there but 2nd thread just can get a chance to get scheduled and complete the I/O in given quantum time.

PS2: `Sleep(0)` : "Hey, O.S. I'm done, you dont need to wait the whole time you assigned for me, to interrupt me. Here you can use whatever time I've got left, I'm just done with it. You can schedule anyone else (if there's no other, you can schedule me again though), if you like. [Sleep Function MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and the quotation:

> After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. If you specify 0 milliseconds, the thread will relinquish the remainder of its time slice but remain ready. Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately. Consequently, the thread may not run until some time after the sleep interval elapses. For more information, see [Scheduling Priorities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: So you seem to say that Sleep(0) solves the problem? Not likely.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No sir, I'm not saying Sleep(0) absolutely solves the problem. What can happen after Sleep(1000) is also can happen after Sleep(0) or Sleep(10000). It was just a pointing out the sync. problem. After reading that, it could be misleading. Editing...